# React native onPress event on Mapview Marker title?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

With my code below, if I click on the marker it navigates to the page I mentioned, but I want this to be implemented on Marker Title not the marker, is there any way to make the title clickable. Any help please.

```
 return (
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      placeholder="Search location"
      minLength={2}
      region={focusRegion}
      // onPress={componentDidMount()}
      onMapReady={getLocationHandler}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      //followsUserLocation={true}
      loadingEnabled={true}
      loadingIndicatorColor={"#606060"}
    >
      {places.map((marker) => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.id}
          coordinate={{ latitude: marker.lat, longitude: marker.lng }}
          title={(marker.title)}
          onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate("PlaceDetail", {
              placeTitle: marker.title,
              placeId: marker.id,
            });
          }}
        >              
            
    </MapView>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with the callout

```
<MapView.Callout
            title={true}
            width={210}
            onPress={() => {
              props.navigation.navigate("PlaceDetail", {
                placeTitle: marker.title,
                placeId: marker.id,
              });
            }}
          ></MapView.Callout>
```